# Fix fragment sizes android

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I have two fragments. Both contains some buttons and list views. And I am displaying these two fragments vertically in separate container. But if the list view contains more items, the below fragment goes down. How can we display two fragments with fixed sizes? i.e. screen should be divided into two.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the top container will cover 70% of the screen and the bottom 30%.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">


    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to hear! You can accept the answer to the left so people know this question has been resolved :)